# Is it better to work with non-contiguous or contiguous polygons?

Tags: polygon, r

I would like to find width-height of a non-contiguous polygon in order to draw paths within it. My question: Is it better to use a bounding box (contiguous polygon) and then clip keeping my real area or to work with the non-contiguous polygon from the beginning?